# Does a Python 3 SOAP client module exist?

Tags: python, soap, python-3.x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the best SOAP library for Python 3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817303/whats-the-best-soap-library-for-python-3-x)

I couldn't find one that works with Python 3.1.  Any suggestions for a WSDL-consuming Python 3 SOAP client module/library?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817303/whats-the-best-soap-library-for-python-3-x#comment11973645_7817303

Comment: Look at Python Wiki: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebServices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could port an existing library that you like and provide your changes to the author of the package.

Comment: I'm a bit new to Python, but I might try using the 2to3 script on one if nobody suggests something else.