# Python 3.4 Bioservices installation

Tags: python, pip, bioservices

I'm trying to install the `bioservices : 1.2.5` on my Windows 7 with Python 3.4 installed. The path has the scripts included but I still continue to have the syntax error when trying to use 'pip install'.

I tried to install 'bioservices' using:

```
sudo pip install bioservices
sudo easy_install bioservices
pip install bioservices
```

Till now nothing worked.

**Edit:*** Now gives me another error:

After running `pip install bioservices`, on `Windows powershell` this error appears

Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in `C:\User\Raquel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Raquel\SOAPpy`

Storing debug log for failure in `C:\User\Raquel\pip\pip.log`

Comment: Can you post the error messages you are getting as well as how you are doing it?

Comment: I do this in the windows powershell with admin rights. python pip install bioservices and the error message is:
File "<stdin>", line 1
  pip install bioservices
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax​

Comment: Another method to installing is to copy the bioservices folder into your `c:/python/Lib` directory. Then run `python setup.py install`.

Comment: @drum thanks that worked, but now using the extention gives me the following error

Comment: BioServices v$Id: __init__.py 320 2014-02-28 13:31:27Z cokelaer $$, $Rev: 320 $ warning: pandas is not installed on your system
Some features requires this library and future version of BioServices may use it.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Raquel\Documents\Universidade\Python\workspace\Array\array.py", line 6, in <module>
    from bioservices import arrayexpress
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\bioservices-1.2.6-py3.4.egg\bioservices\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'services'

Answer (score 0):

BioServices depends on SOAPpy for the WSDL services.
Unfortunately, it looks like SOAPpy is not available for Python 3 (see e.g., 
[What SOAP libraries exist for Python 3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817303/whats-the-best-soap-library-for-python-3-x) ).

This may be the reason why the installation fails with

```
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in C:\User\Raquel\AppData\Loca\Temp\pip_build_Raquel\SOAPpy
```