# SOAP/WSDL web services and Python nowadays

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, soap-client

First of all: Yes, I know that there are plenty of SOAP/WSDL/Python Questions. And no, none of the answers I found was really helpful (anymore).

Secondly: Yes, I wouldn't use SOAP/WSDL anymore if I wouldn't need to. Unfortunately there are still huge software companies only offering web service through this interface. And I have to communicate with such a system. The specific company suggests the usage of PHP but I'm not really a PHP fan when it comes to serious things. I know that there seem to be good SOAP solutions for Java but Java is no option in this context.

The problem: There exists a multitude of SOAP packages for Python and quite some of them support WSDL. Foremost SOAPpy and ZSI. Unfortunately they usually depend on PyXML, which isn't compatible to recent Python versions anymore. I'm fine with Python 3 or Python 2.7, but nothing previous to that.

Since I don't want to ride a dead horse: Are there still any solutions to use SOAP / WSDL within current Python versions?

Answer (score 0):

Check out: [What SOAP libraries exist for Python 3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817303/what-soap-libraries-exist-for-python-3-x)

I've used suds before and it feels good. It does seem pysimplesoap is more maintained though - I've only used pysimplesoap server side, not for consuming (e. client).