# SOAPpy module python 3

Tags: python-3.x, soap

I am working on python script to make SOAP api call to create Incident in Service-Now. I downloaded SOAPPy using pip. However when i tried to import SOAPProxy module I keep getting below error

from SOAPpy import SOAPProxy

error:

from version import **version**

ImportError: No module named 'version'.

(I am using Windows machine and Python 3.5.1)

If SOAPpy is not supported in python 3, Please let me know other supported SOAP modules for python 3.

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, you might want to have a look at alternative libraries, some of which are listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817303/what-soap-libraries-exist-for-python-3-x

Comment: [Similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56480825/5320906)