# Installing SOAPpy in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, soap, client, soappy

I'm trying to install SOAPpy library in python 3 . I get the following error

```
"/../Downloads/SOAPpy-0.11.6/SOAPpy/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from version import __version__
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'version'
```

I tried to install the other alternative that has been suggested in the other posts , e.g. zeep . But the url that I have to use has `soap` in it and is not working with the other alternatives.

The following is the example script that I am using from here

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import string
import hashlib
from SOAPpy import WSDL ## for extracting the URL of the endpoint (server script) from the WSDL file
from SOAPpy import SOAPProxy ## for usage without WSDL file

#1) Usage with WSDL (for extracting the URL of the endpoint)
wsdl = "https://www.brenda-enzymes.org/soap/brenda.wsdl"
password = hashlib.sha256("myPassword").hexdigest()
client = WSDL.Proxy(wsdl)
parameters = "j.doe@example.edu,"+password+",ecNumber*1.1.1.1#organism*Homo sapiens#"
resultString = client.getKmValue(parameters)
print resultString
```

I would like to ask for suggestions on how this can be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The version module is part of the SOAPpy package, but in Python 3 you'd need to use absolute imports,

```
from SOAPpy.version import __version__   
or 
from .version import __version__ in your __init__ installer package file.
```

There will be other issues with the code too.

Here's a link which supports SOAPpy for python3 https://pypi.org/project/SOAPpy-py3/