# Using a SOAP WSDL with python

Tags: python

I have been trying to wrap my head around a few things and I havent found a concrete solution for the same.

I want to use a SOAP web service to get an XML data and then parse the received XML data.

So far, I have only found libraries compatible with python 2.xx and I want something comaptible with python 3.xx. I have tried Zeep but I wasnt able to configure it as its module was released on May 15th.

Anyway, I would like to be guided towards a library which can help me setup a SOAP client on python 3.6 allowing me to use its methods to send requests and consume the response.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What SOAP libraries exist for Python 3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817303/what-soap-libraries-exist-for-python-3-x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My research has shown zeep is really the only currently maintained one. I'm using python 3.6 and using it for SOAP (5/2019).

Quick google search came up with these links which are fresh for 5/2019:
[What SOAP libraries exist for Python 3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817303/what-soap-libraries-exist-for-python-3-x) which I believe is already referenced in the comments (I'm new and can't comment).

Another link 
https://www.slant.co/topics/268/~best-soap-client-libraries-for-python is good, though the "last updated" column is misleading. Zeep has been updated with in months, but the others have not been updated in years.