# Support of python3.x for SOAP library Soapbox?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, soap, python-3.x

I am developing a server using only Python 3.x on Django or any other Framework (to be decided).

My requirement is to use a SOAP library to process SOAP XML messages. However, I am not sure whether the SOAP Library Soapbox is supported by Python 3.x.

When installing Soapbox using Python 3.3, following error i am getting,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 14, in <module>
    from requirements import RequirementsParser
  File "/home/pawan/tornado/soaplib/Soapbox/Soapbox-0.3.7/requirements.py", line 437
    except OSError, e:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But with Python 2.7, it is being installed successfully.

Your suggestion and help would be highly appreciated in this matter of Python 3.x support for Soapbox.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Python 3.x is supported for Soapbox. In the Python package index it is listed under Python 2.7.

However, there are forks on github that attempt to ensure compatibility with Python 3.x.

Take a look at:

https://github.com/FelixSchwarz/soapbox-bsd

Commit history shows active development towards trying to achieve compatibility with 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

There is (or at least there was, as of a few months ago when I tried to work with it) very, very poor support for SOAP in py3k. If you can avoid using the two in combination, that would really be ideal.

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817303/whats-the-best-soap-library-for-python-3-x?rq=1), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233298/soap-client-for-python-3), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534554/does-a-python-3-soap-client-module-exist), there really isn't any good python 3 SOAP library. For my project I went with [PySimpleSOAP](http://code.google.com/p/pysimplesoap/), but it wasn't really a fun experience. For whatever reason, there doesn't seem to be very much interest in SOAP in the Python community.