# Is there a module for (at least) non-wsdl soap client for Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, soap-client

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does a Python 3 SOAP client module exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534554/does-a-python-3-soap-client-module-exist)

Seems like [there is no WSDL client](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1534554/772981), but maybe a generic one exists?

By the way, I am not sure if closing questions like [What's the best SOAP library for Python 3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7817303/772981) is that good. It would be good to close it if there existed many solutions, but if we haven't any, I would expect such a question to stay open until something emerges.

Comment: @Tichodroma Notice this is already linked in the question and that it asks about wsdl client. One may edit the title of that question to make it more clear.

Comment: I hope this is closed by Python experts who closed that to state that there is no python module: neither for wsdl (the other question) nor for non-wsdl access (this question).